# Можно ли использовать разные реализации в разных бинарях для одного объявления?

Tags: c++, функции, сборка, объявление

Нормальная ли практика использовать разные реализации в разных бинарях для одного объявления? Или это может привести к каким-то проблемам?

Например:

```cpp
// global_declarations.h
void init_all();

// app_1.cpp
#include "global_declarations.h"
void init_all() { ... } // first implementation

// app_2.cpp
#include "global_declarations.h"
void init_all() { ... } // second implementation
```

Здесь `app_1.exe` и `app_2.exe` - два разных бинаря.

Comment: Почему бы и нет, что вас смущает? Если не пытаться линковать две версии функции в одном бинарнике, то всё ОК.

Comment: @LShadow77 по умолчанию полагаешь, что реализации одинаковые, поэтому это может быть неочевидно. Ещё мб проблемы с навигацией по коду будут. Вообще, этот вопрос как раз про возможные минусы, которых я не знаю)

Comment: А как же тогда библиотечные объявления? В инклюдах они не меняются, а реализации внутри библиотек от версии к версии могут отличаться. Тут по аналогии. Важно просто понимать процесс сборки, который состоит из двух этапов: компиляция исходников в объектные модули; связывание модулей в готовый бинарник (exe, dll). Если на линкер попадут два разных модуля с одноимёнными функциями, то тогда возникнет конфликт имён. Чтобы этого не было, надо просто грамотно организовать проект(ы). А так, расшаренные инклюды - распространённая практика.